# Align dropdown and input

Tags: css, angular, ng2-completer

I have a issue with css and ng2-completer. I try to align the dropdown part and the input. 
There is no example on the demo page to focus element with css and when i try to select the class .completer-dropdown-holder i have no result.

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve] demonstrating your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can override the class for the options and set the left property. I think the class name is mat-option but you can double check by inspecting the element through dev tools. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best solution but with display flex it's fine for my case.

```
.completer-dropdown-holder {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```